# How to LIMIT a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to LEFT JOIN only 5 child rows to a parent row.  Here is the query

```
SELECT child.* FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE category='general' LIMIT 10) as parent
  LEFT JOIN
  mytable as child on child.parentid=parent.id
  ORDER by parent.id ASC
```

This fetches all child rows for a specific parent row, when i only want 5 max.

Here is an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d9e7/2 the real data is many more.

How do i LIMIT so only 5 child row are shown for a specific parent row? Right now 7 child rows with parentid 1 are being shown.  I want only 5 child rows per parent row to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way in MySQL is to enumerate the rows using variables and choose the first five:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT child.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = parent.id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := parent.id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE category='general' LIMIT 10
           ) parent LEFT JOIN
           mytable child
           on child.parentid=parent.id CROSS JOIN
           (select @id := -1, @rn := 0) vars
      ORDER by parent.id ASC
     ) c
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  First question performance wise if i had 10000s of rows is this the most efficient way?  Secondly, can you explain what you did with the variables, i don't understand what you did.

Comment: Using variables is likely to be faster than other methods.  Whether your query is optimal or not depends on the indexes and number of children for the parents.  If you are concerned about performance, ask another question specifically about performance and put the table and index structures in the question.